# Is there a speed benefit to using unsafe code in .Net to swap objects of complex types?

Tags: .net, performance, unsafe

Here is my current swap code for swapping 2 KeyValuePair objects in an array:

```
KeyValuePair<int, T> t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
```

Would there be any speed advantage to using unsafe code and merely swapping the pointers of the 2 objects? Or does the complier effectively boil this safe code down to effectively doing just that?

Comment: Just FYI: [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx), so those aren't "pointers" in the array; they're the values themselves (each consisting of a `TKey` and a `TValue`) -- though, obviously, `TKey` and/or `TValue` could be reference types.

Comment: Ah, right, KeyValuePair is a struct, not a class. Thanks @Dan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't be any faster.

This is premature micro-optimization at its worst.

In fact, it will be orders of magnitude slower, since you'll need to pin the array (using the [`fixed` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) in order to get a pointer to it.

Comment: Not to mention that with marshalling data across managed/unmanaged boundaries, it will most likely be WORSE.

Comment: @Blindy: Wrong; that's only for COM and P/Invoke.

Comment: Just asking purely from an "understanding the framework" point of view.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space for .Net pointers in per optimization. Not much in your particular case but stuff like Circular Redundancy Check, pointers can give us more optimum solution.